# Visual Studio Code Flutter Format is Not Working with My Indent Space Value

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, indentation

I wasted my all day and i didnt understand what is going on. I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.40.2 and i am learning Flutter 3.60. Sometimes Flutter codes turn unreadable because of indent space. I only wanted to create more space (indent space) but when i use format option, tab size is turning again 2. I looked too many web sites including Stackoverflow and unfortunately i didnt find solution.It turned annoying. This is my config file: (Thanks for help)

```
{
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
"editor.fontSize": 18,
"editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace, ",
"dart.openDevTools": "flutter",
"workbench.colorTheme": "Night Owl (No Italics)",
"workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
"editor.fastScrollSensitivity": 8,
"editor.tabSize": 8,
"editor.insertSpaces": true,
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"editor.smoothScrolling": true,
"editor.cursorBlinking": "expand",
"editor.cursorSmoothCaretAnimation": true,
"editor.fontWeight": "400",
"outline.showFields": false,

"[dart]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 6,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
},
```

}

- I changed editor.insertSpaces false and true and nothing changed.
- editor.detectIndentation true or false is not working.
- I added this block but didnt worked.

  "[flutter]": {
          "editor.tabSize": 6,
          "editor.insertSpaces": true,
          "editor.detectIndentation": false,
      },

This is my simple code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GridListe extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        primary: false,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        crossAxisSpacing: 20,
        mainAxisSpacing: 40,
        children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.teal,
                child: Text(
                "Salam",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
            ),
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

When i use format code (Shift + alt + p) Codes indent space or tab size turn 2 and it will make me crazy.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GridListe extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      primary: false,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      crossAxisSpacing: 20,
      mainAxisSpacing: 40,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.teal,
          child: Text(
            "Salam",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `dartfmt` always intends to 2 spaces - you can't control that.

Comment: Sometimes i watch tutorials and when they use Android Studio,they have more indent spaces...I think problem is about VSC settings.

Comment: @BurakİbrahimÜnal Unfortunately it's not just settings - see my answer below. Android Studio/IntelliJ do have more options, because they parse the Dart code themselves and get a lot of functionality from the IDE framework - that's not the case for VS Code, so we only have the SDK-provided formatting.

Comment: search for formatOnSave in the settings and enable it

Answer (score 81):

Add your this in your settings.json file

```
"[dart]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
   "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
```

Comment: I also typed this lines... Nothing changed. I already wrote above .Unfortunately dart sdk dont support to change indent space.

Comment: Removing `"[dart]":` in this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

Just add the below code in your `ProjectDir/ProjectName/.vscode/settings.json`

```
   {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
 }
```

Comment: very nice work for me

Answer (score 3):

Edit a file name settings.json inside .vscode folder
***note: {if not available create like this}***

then paste this json

```
{
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
     },
}
```

follow these instruction ->
[image: Create settings.json file inside .vscode folder]
[image: Write this json]

Answer (score 2):

The Dart extension for VS Code uses the formatter from the Dart SDK ([dart_style](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style)) which does not support customising the indent options (by design) so it will always use 2-spaces.

It is possible to disable the built-in formatter should you wish to format manually, and it's also possible for other VS Code extensions to contribute formatters for Dart - though as far as I am aware none have (yet) been created (though I have offered assistance [in this issue](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/914) should someone be interested in creating a VS Code extension to do this).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Settings (json)
2. Find [dart] and add "editor.tabSize": 4

Answer (score 0):

If your `FormatOnSave` doesn't work you can check if there is one more existing keybindings set to the same key as the `File:save` in your VS Code, because that could also stop your `FormatOnSave` to work. Hope it helps!